# Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up box?

Tags: css, facebook, button, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'd like to disable the Comment box that pops up when a user clicks the Facebook Like button ,

I followed the post [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)  and changed the CSS  But it didnt work any other suggestions please

I cant use IFRAME otherwise i would not be able to use FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/:

> **When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?**
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will always have the option to add a comment. > If you are using the Iframe version of the button, users will have the option to comments if you are using > the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 400 pixels. If users do add a comment, the story published > back to Facebook is given more prominence.

Just use the iframe version of the button and set the width to less than 400 pixels.

Comment: But if i use IFRAME then i would now be able to use FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

Comment: The iframe version disallows all event callbacks. Bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a style attribute with overflow: hidden

```
<div style="overflow: hidden !important;" class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the iframe within a div and use overflow hidden with a width and height that hides anything except for the button.

I tried to change the css from within the iframe but that didn't work for me.

Comment: But if i use IFRAME then i would now be able to use FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

Answer (score 0):

create a custom css class like,

```
.fb-like{
overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

mention the class into facebook DIV

That's it...