# Disable comment popup on facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to hide the comment popup that comes up when a facebook like is done. I've tried with giving css

```
.-cx-PRIVATE-pluginCommentFlyout__fullButton {
    display: none !important;
    }
```

but that doesn't seems to work as the css is added dynamically through jquery I assume.
How can I hide this comment box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered in some other threads:

[Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742492/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up-box)

[Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Some answers might already be deprecated, but it´s worth a try. One solution that worked for me some months ago was to use the iframe-version and a width of less than 400px.

Answer (score 3):

The comment box do not appear anymore after clicking like button.

1. Go to [Facebook Like Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
2. Enter details for your implementation of the Like button
3. Click on "Get Code" button
4. There are 4 sections you can choose from (HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME, URL), 

   choose IFRAME and copy the plugin code from IFRAME section.

> Summary: Instead of copying the plugin code from HTML5 section copy
>   the one from IFRAME section.

Comment: It works but the alignment of the button (I'm using box_count layout) is broken.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that none of the older versions is working anylonger. That comment box always appears on my fb like buttons.

Comment: yes the same problem exists with this, i tried with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up approach and it worked out for me

Comment: In my understanding, the comment box appears when the Javascript SDK is used.