# How to disable facebook like button comment pop up?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I would like to disable to pop up facebook like button comment when user click the like button.

I followed these posts:

[Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742492/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up-box)

[Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

I tried for CSS

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This did not work.

I tried

```
fb-like {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This worked when I checked with PC, but it does not work when I check it with iPhone.

Could you tell me how to disable facebook like button comment pop up?

Comment: You can’t, and you are not supposed to. It is default functionality of the plugin, and you are not allowed to mess with that. If Facebook wanted this configurable, they would have provided an option for it.